# Paginacion usando JEE

Tags: java, html

Tengo una duda sobre como hacer una paginacion utilizando JEE y HTML.
Tengo una funcion que me devuelve una lista de productos, utilizando las taglibs he logrado colocar estos productos en un elemento "ul" en una pagina web.

Lo que queria hacer era una paginacion para que solo se viesen 7 elementos en una pagina.

Tenia pensado usar las taglibs para que estos productos se coloquen en la pagina hasta que hayan 7 y cuando sean mas que 7 se cree abajo de la lista de productos un boton que diga Siguiente pagina (o algo similar) y que al dar click a esto se borre los productos que hay y coloquen los siguientes 7 productos.

(No quiero crear un link que me redirija a otra pagina web, quiero que se modifique ahi mismo).

Pero no he sabido como detectar el click en "Siguiente pagina" para que haga su funcion. Espero haberme explicado bien y que puedan ayudarme.

Por lo tanto, mi duda especifica seria como puedo hacer que al clickar en este "Siguiente pagina" se elimine los productos que hay y se coloquen los 7 siguientes.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a [es.so]. Por favor has el [tour] y lee [ask] para formular mejor tu pregunta. Te sugiero consultar el uso de [acordeones jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) ofrecen la funcionalidad que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

en definitiva es posible, pero suena a mucho trabajo manual ... la logica sería la siguiente :

JSF / XHTML

Tener un ui:repeat  o un c:forEach que reciba una lista de tus elementos productos, esa lista de elementos unicamente deberia incluir la cantidad de elementos que deseas mostrar , por ejemplo :

```
 <c:forEach items="#{beanUI.listaProductos}" var="item">
     <div class="single-product-item">  ITEM
     </div>
</c:forEach>
```

De esta forma controlas que aparezcan N productos en tu página, para el tema del paginador deberia ser algo similar , igual a ver si te sirve este ejemplo :

```
 Pagina actual : #{beanUI.paginaActual}

                            <center><ul class="paginationcolor">
                                    <li><a jsf:actionListener="#{beanUI.regresar()}" >«</a></li>
                                    <li><a jsf:actionListener="#{beanUI.PrimerPagina()}" >««</a></li>

                                    <c:forEach items="#{beanUI.Paginas}" var="pages">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="#{beanUI.clasePagina(pages.intValue())}" jsf:actionListener="#{beanUI.paginaSet(pages.intValue())}">#{pages.intValue()+1}</a></li>

                                    </c:forEach>
                                    <li><a jsf:actionListener="#{catalogoBean.ultima()}" >»»</a></li>
                                    <li><a jsf:actionListener="#{beanUI.siguiente()}" >»</a></li>

                                     </ul></center>
```

En el cual, Paginas es la cantidad de elementos por pagina que quedan, se puede sacar con una operación matematica, si tienes 100 elementos y quieres mostrar 10 por pagina seria 100/10 para tener 10 paginas con 10 elementos, te toca hacer la operación a ti :P

En tu clase de Java en el Bean tendrías que obtener ya sea de la base de datos o de donde lo tengas tus productos, si tu lista o array de objetos en el que unicamente deberas presentar en pantalla los 7 elementos que tu deseas, como logras eso ? bueno eso ya es chamba de la logica que tienes que averiguar, pero como una pequeña orientación sería jugar con los limit 0,7 con query a la base de datos, o si no haces ninguna conexion dividiedo tu lista en listas de 7 elementos...

Lo que yo haría ;

Utilizar un framework para jsf como Primefaces ( y muchos otros )

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datagrid/basic.xhtml

Solo mandas llamar el componente en tu vista , le pasas una lista y presto !